# using preg_match : user#345

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to use a preg match , that my users can register with this type of username :
name#3digit

I have problem with using #.
what is the problem of this code :

```
if (!preg_match("/(\w+)#(?P\d{3})/",$_REQUEST['irc_channel']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this part `?P`, cos of it's named sub-pattern. So if you need then might use it proper. See: [PHP: Subpatterns - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)

This would be giving what you want;

```
$r = preg_match('~(\w+)#(\d+)~i', 'user#345', $m);
print_r($r); // 1
print_r($m); // Array([0] => user#345 [1] => user [2] => 345)

$r = preg_match('~(\w+)#(\d+)~i', 'user......#345', $m);
print_r($r); // 0 error!
```

What if you need sub-patterns? (But as far as I see you don't need any array result in this case, just checking the input is valid or not).

```
$r = preg_match('~(\w+)#(?P<id>\d+)~i', 'user#345', $m);
print_r($m); // Array([0] => user#345 [1] => user [id] => 345 [2] => 345)
```

So finally;

```
if (!preg_match('~(\w+)#(\d+)~i', $_REQUEST['irc_channel'])) 
// actually this would work too
if (!preg_match('~\w+#\d+~i', $_REQUEST['irc_channel']))
```